# How to find the transition matrix $B$ to $B'$, given that both are linearly independent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

How to find the transition matrix from basis $B$ to basis $B'$ given that $B$ and $B'$ are both sets of linearly independent matrices?

From what I understand, if $B$ and $B'$ are sets of vectors, you can get the transition matrix $P$ if you construct an augmented matrix  $[B'|B]$ then apply row operations to $B'$ to get the transition  matrix $P$ from the transformed $B$. I was wondering if the same is  applicable if the set contains matrices (say $3\times3$) instead of vectors.